# How to use c# inside mvc razor pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm new to asp.net core.

I want to display max 4 items per row, and using c# in razor views to manipulate dom.

however at some points the c# code seems faded and the code does not work.

below is an image to show you what I mean.
if I put a @ sign in front of the ifs it works however this time at the last If statement it gives an error to the div statement, It requires me to have an opening div tag however that tag is in the first if. any help is much appreciated
 [image]

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Provide code in the form of text. It will be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should not put closing tags in conditional statements.
In this case you should move both opening and closing tags of container out of conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like this you need to use `@helper`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site

Razor needs to know that the div will get closed, if you're adding conditions then there's no guarantee that it will.